# QuantLib bond pricing with credit spread not working after setting values of key rate quote

Tags: python, quantlib

I am using SpreadedLinearZeroInterpolatedTermStructure class to price bond. I have 35 key rates, from 1M to 30Y. I also have a daily spot curve. So I want to input 35 key rates extracted from the daily spot curve to the class, then change key rates to see what's the bond price.

Giving credit to GB, and his article here:
http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/bonds-with-spreads-quantlib-python.html

I followed his method which worked well, the bond price is changing due to the different values set to key rates.

Then I substituted his flat curve with my daily spot curve, his handles list with my handles (35 handles in it), and his two dates with my 35 dates.

I set values to some of the key rates while the NPV stayed still(even I gave a huge shock). I also tried to give only two key rates on a zero curve, and it worked. So I guess it's because 35 key rates is way too much? Any help is appreciated

```
import QuantLib as ql

# =============================================================================
# normal yc term structure
# =============================================================================
todaysDate = ql.Date(24,5,2019)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = todaysDate

KR1 = [0, 1, 3, 6, 9] # KR in month unit
KR2 = [x for x in range(1,31)] # KR in year unit
spotDates = [] # starting from today
for kr in KR1:
    p = ql.Period(kr,ql.Months)
    spotDates.append(todaysDate+p)
for kr in KR2:
    p = ql.Period(kr,ql.Years)
    spotDates.append(todaysDate+p)

spotRates = [0.02026,
             0.021569,
             0.02326,
             0.025008,
             0.026089,
             0.026679,
             0.028753,
             0.029376,
             0.030246,
             0.031362,
             0.033026,
             0.034274,
             0.033953,
             0.033474,
             0.033469,
             0.033927,
             0.03471,
             0.035596,
             0.036396,
             0.036994,
             0.037368,
             0.037567,
             0.037686,
             0.037814,
             0.037997,
             0.038247,
             0.038562,
             0.038933,
             0.039355,
             0.039817,
             0.040312,
             0.040832,
             0.041369,
             0.041922,
             0.042487] # matching points
dayCount = ql.Thirty360()
calendar = ql.China()
interpolation = ql.Linear()
compounding = ql.Compounded
compoundingFrequency = ql.Annual
spotCurve = ql.ZeroCurve(spotDates, spotRates, dayCount, calendar, 
                         interpolation,compounding, compoundingFrequency)
spotCurveHandle = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(spotCurve)

# =============================================================================
# bond settings
# =============================================================================
issue_date = ql.Date(24,5,2018)
maturity_date = ql.Date(24,5,2023)
tenor = ql.Period(ql.Semiannual)
calendar = ql.China()
business_convention = ql.Unadjusted
date_generation = ql.DateGeneration.Backward
month_end = False
schedule = ql.Schedule(issue_date,maturity_date,tenor,calendar,
                       business_convention, business_convention,
                       date_generation,month_end)
settlement_days = 0
day_count = ql.Thirty360()
coupon_rate = 0.03
coupons = [coupon_rate]

face_value = 100
fixed_rate_bond = ql.FixedRateBond(settlement_days,
                                   face_value,
                                   schedule,
                                   coupons,
                                   day_count)
#bond_engine = ql.DiscountingBondEngine(spotCurveHandle)
#fixed_rate_bond.setPricingEngine(bond_engine)
#print(fixed_rate_bond.NPV())


# =============================================================================
# non-parallel shift of yc
# =============================================================================

#def KRshocks(kr0=0.0, kr_1M=0.0, kr_3M=0.0, kr_6M=0.0, kr_9M=0.0, 
#             kr_1Y=0.0,kr_2Y=0.0, kr_3Y=0.0, kr_4Y=0.0, kr_5Y=0.0, kr_6Y=0.0,
#             kr_7Y=0.0, kr_8Y=0.0, kr_9Y=0.0, kr_10Y=0.0, kr_11Y=0.0, kr_12Y=0.0,
#             kr_13Y=0.0, kr_14Y=0.0, kr_15Y=0.0, kr_16Y=0.0, kr_17Y=0.0, kr_18Y=0.0,
#             kr_19Y=0.0, kr_20Y=0.0, kr_21Y=0.0, kr_22Y=0.0, kr_23Y=0.0, kr_24Y=0.0,
#             kr_25Y=0.0, kr_26Y=0.0, kr_27Y=0.0, kr_28Y=0.0, kr_29Y=0.0, kr_30Y=0.0):
#    '''
#    
#    Parameters:
#        Input shocks for each key rate.
#        kr0 = today's spot rate shock;
#        kr_1M = 0.083 year(1 month) later spot rate shock;
#        kr_1Y = 1 year later spot rate shock;
#        .
#        .
#        .
#        
#    '''
#    
#    krs = list(locals().keys())
#    KRHandles = {}
#    for k in krs:
#        KRHandles['{}handle'.format(k)] = ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(locals()[k]))

#    return list(KRHandles.values())

#handles = KRshocks()

kr = ['kr0', 'kr_1M', 'kr_3M', 'kr_6M', 'kr_9M', 'kr_1Y','kr_2Y', 'kr_3Y', 
      'kr_4Y', 'kr_5Y', 'kr_6Y','kr_7Y', 'kr_8Y', 'kr_9Y', 'kr_10Y', 'kr_11Y', 
      'kr_12Y', 'kr_13Y', 'kr_14Y', 'kr_15Y', 'kr_16Y', 'kr_17Y', 'kr_18Y', 
      'kr_19Y', 'kr_20Y', 'kr_21Y', 'kr_22Y', 'kr_23Y', 'kr_24Y','kr_25Y', 
      'kr_26Y', 'kr_27Y', 'kr_28Y', 'kr_29Y', 'kr_30Y']

#KRQuotes = {}
handles = []
#for k in range(len(kr)):
#    KRQuotes['{}'.format(kr[k])] = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[k])
#    handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[k])))

kr0 = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[0])
kr_1M = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[1])
kr_3M = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[2])
kr_6M = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[3])
kr_9M = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[4])
kr_1Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[5])
kr_2Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[6])
kr_3Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[7])
kr_4Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[8])
kr_5Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[9])
kr_6Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[10])
kr_7Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[11])
kr_8Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[12])
kr_9Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[13])
kr_10Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[14])
kr_11Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[15])
kr_12Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[16])
kr_13Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[17])
kr_14Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[18])
kr_15Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[19])
kr_16Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[20])
kr_17Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[21])
kr_18Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[22])
kr_19Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[23])
kr_20Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[24])
kr_21Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[25])
kr_22Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[26])
kr_23Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[27])
kr_24Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[28])
kr_25Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[29])
kr_26Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[30])
kr_27Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[31])
kr_28Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[32])
kr_29Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[33])
kr_30Y = ql.SimpleQuote(spotRates[34])

handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr0))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_1M))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_3M))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_6M))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_9M))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_1Y))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_2Y))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_3Y))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_4Y))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_5Y))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_6Y))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_7Y))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_8Y))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_9Y))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_10Y))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_11Y))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_12Y))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_13Y))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_14Y))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_15Y))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_16Y))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_17Y))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_18Y))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_19Y))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_20Y))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_21Y))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_22Y))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_23Y))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_24Y))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_25Y))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_26Y))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_27Y))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_28Y))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_29Y))
handles.append(ql.QuoteHandle(kr_30Y))

ts_spreaded2 = ql.SpreadedLinearZeroInterpolatedTermStructure(spotCurveHandle,
                                                              handles,
                                                              spotDates)
ts_spreaded_handle2 = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ts_spreaded2)
bond_engine = ql.DiscountingBondEngine(ts_spreaded_handle2)
fixed_rate_bond.setPricingEngine(bond_engine)
#print(fixed_rate_bond.NPV())
kr0.setValue(0.1)
kr_10Y.setValue(0.2)
kr_12Y.setValue(0.2)
print(fixed_rate_bond.NPV())
```

no errors came out but the bond price is the same as the price before spreads added

Comment: Сan you come up with reproducible example - a code that one can copy and run a locsl machine.It has to have proper imports, among other things. This way your question is more easoly adressable.

Comment: Sure. I'll modify the code.